# Cooliris fetching from google docs:

Tags: rss, google-docs, cooliris

We're creating a Interaction design pattern website for a class.
We've been using google docs to create the patterns list during the classes, sharing it with the teacher for evaluation.

So the environment is this:

- We've been able to fetch a single image from each presentation we want to display, such as: http://docs.google.com/file?id=dd2dpzk6_164zcwm3jgv_b
- We've created an RSS feed for cooliris to open: (small example from it):

  <.item>

  ```
  <.title>e7_pattern_7.78<./title>

  <.link>http://docs.google.com/file?id=dd2dpzk6_164zcwm3jgv_b<./link>

  <.guid>dd2dpzk6_164zcwm3jgv_b<./guid>

  <.media:thumbnail url="http://docs.google.com/file?id=dd2dpzk6_164zcwm3jgv_b" />

  <.media:content url="http://docs.google.com/file?id=dd2dpzk6_164zcwm3jgv_b" type="image/png" />
  ```

  <./item>

Sorry for the points in the middle of the tag is only for stackoverflow not to filter it.

So the problem is the following, the rss works correctly, as the cooliris opens all viewports for all images. But both the thumbnail and content remain black for all the pictures.

If you try to open them by the above url you can download them, with the type="image/png" if should work for piclens to open it.

Anyone got a sugestion or idea why we can't access the images from google docs via cooliris ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server needed a crossdomain.xml to allow cooliris. So we can't do it directly from google but we'll just download it a put on another server.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting type="image/png" in the media:thumbnail tag too.. additionally, put your feed through an RSS validator, just to see if it checks out..

Comment: ty for the reply but it was a crossdomain.xml that was needed and ofcourse google doesn't have it :P

Comment: Are you using the embeddable flash wall?